# Change locale in Netbeans platform application

Tags: netbeans

I need to change the locale of a netbeans platform app (7.1) to "de". Does anyone know where this is set? I tried the line netbeans_default_options="--locale de" in project.properties but that wasn´t it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1) Passing the locale to java arguments:

```
-Duser.language=de -Duser.region=DE
```

2) Call Locale.setDefault()

```
locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
```

Comment: I´ve probably described my problem poorly, sorry. I don´t need Java to take on the locale, i need the whole netbeans platform GUI to switch to German.

Comment: You mean menus of netbeans etc? Check this link: http://netbeans.dzone.com/multilingual-netbeans-platform-applications