# Coding a menu that allows user to select a language

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

How would I go about coding a menu that will allow the user to select a language and thereafter the user will have his whole program rendered in the language of his choice?

Note: I'm using Netbeans and one of the tutorials suggested using automatic internalization to make the bundle.properties files.

What I don't know is how to set the language to selected option.
Please explain in detail as I can barely understand what I'm doing right now.

```
int sel = cmbLang.getSelectedIndex();
    switch (sel) {
        case 0:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please make a selection");
            break;
        case 1:
            fmt:setLocale(Locale.E);//set language to language 1 
            break;
        case 2:
            //set Language to language 2
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190404/change-locale-in-netbeans-platform-application) you could use `Locale.setDefault(Locale yourDesiredLocale)`(see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale))) to change the language.

Comment: From my understanding the application will have to be restarted for this to take effect, is this true??

Comment: Yes, according to [this](http://netbeans.dzone.com/multilingual-netbeans-platform-applications) article in the comments a restart is needed.

Comment: I wouldn't get my hopes up that this will be possible without a restart in the near future. What hinders you from restarting your app?

PS: You could try your luck on the Netbeans Platform Dev Mailing List [here](https://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html#dev). Always seems to be more helpful regarding Netbeans Platform questions then StackOverflow, unfortunatliy.